# Not able perform HDFS file system commands being owner of the Home directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I am one of the user in HDFS file system. It seems something broken and not able to create file/directory in my own home directory also.

As part of troubleshooting, i tried giving full permission to my home directory, but still no luck.

For instance say my user name is venkat and host name is localhost.

```
[venkat@localhost ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user | grep venkat
drwxrwxrwx   - venkat                hdfs          0 2019-08-13 03:40 /user/venkat

[venkat@localhost ~]$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/venkat/test
mkdir: Permission denied: user=venkat, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/venkat/test":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-x---
```

It seems by default HDFS is considering other user as owner or taking some default permissions and failing.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: We are facing same permission denied issue for few of the service accounts while starting those services. Suspecting some common issue leading all problems.

Comment: We have enabled kerberos in our cluster. I could see below logs in namenode log while creating directory.

`2019-08-13 11:26:23,847 INFO  ipc.Server (Server.java:logException(2428)) - IPC Server handler 14 on 8020, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.mkdirs from 10.208.57.7:59528 Call#2 Retry#0: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=venkat, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/venkat/test":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-x---`

Answer (score 0):

Realized how much time wasted for this issue after finding the solution.
I am happy to provide answer for this issue myself.
The issue was permissions with /user directory.

Before:

```
drwxr-x---   - hdfs          hdfs            0 2019-08-13 03:41 /user
```

After:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs          hdfs            0 2019-08-13 03:41 /user
```